# dotted outline around links for IE7+

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, outline

I am not able to get rid of dotted outline in IE7+. I have added `outline:none; border:none` but still it is  not working in any version of IE.

I have created fiddle, it works fine when I run the fiddle age in IE but when I paste the same code in HTML page then it is not working. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6Ayek/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Photos Tab</title>
<style type="text/css">
/* Generated by F12 developer tools. This might not be an accurate representation of the original source file */
#contentContainer { BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(/s/store/-1/common/gb/Media-Console/popup_bg.jpg); WIDTH: 636px; HEIGHT: 460px; OVERFLOW: auto}
#leftNavigation {   PADDING-LEFT: 15px; WIDTH: 125px; PADDING-RIGHT: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; FLOAT: left; FONT-SIZE: 12px}
#leftNavigation ul {PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px}
#leftNavigation ul li { WIDTH: 125px; DISPLAY: block;  outline:none !important;}
#leftNavigation ul li a {LINE-HEIGHT: 30px;  DISPLAY: block; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #2c2f30; FONT-SIZE: 12px;; TEXT-DECORATION: none; outline:none !important;}
#leftNavigation ul li a:visited {   COLOR: #2c2f30; outline:none !important; border:none}
#leftNavigation ul li a:hover { COLOR: #000000;  outline:none !important; border:none}
.currentSelection { BORDER-BOTTOM: #0076a3 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #0076a3 1px solid; LINE-HEIGHT: 25px; OUTLINE-STYLE: none; OUTLINE-COLOR: invert; PADDING-LEFT: 10px; OUTLINE-WIDTH: medium; DISPLAY: inline-block; BACKGROUND: #0095cd; BORDER-TOP: #0076a3 1px solid; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; BORDER-RIGHT: #0076a3 1px solid; TEXT-DECORATION: none; BEHAVIOR: url('/s/store/-1/common/gb/Media-Console/PIE.htc'); -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; 
}   
</style>
 </head>    
<body>
<div id="leftNavigation">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#" style="color: white; " class="currentSelection">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="color: black; ">test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="color: black; ">test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="color: black; ">test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="color: black; ">test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Do **NOT** remove the visual focus indicator, your users need it! 1- example: I want confirmation that I clicked somewhere and when going back from which link I was coming. 2-accessibility related, please read [WCAG 2.0 F78 Failure Technique](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/F78.html), [C15](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/C15.html) and [SCR31](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/SCR31.html) related to what you shouldn't achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need one short CSS rule for this:

```
a { outline: none }
```

Why it’s not working in your HTML page is impossible to answer, but this is the correct CSS code for removing outlines.

I should mention that this technique is not very accessibility-friendly, since the dotted borders are helpful for people that navigates through keyboard or other instruments. A better approach would be this jQuery snippet:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on('mousedown mouseup', 'a', function(e) {
        if ('hideFocus' in this) { // IE
            this.hideFocus = e.type == 'mousedown';
        }
        this.blur();
    });
}(jQuery));
```

**UPDATE**

I misread the `IE7` part of your question... You can try adding:

```
a:focus{
    noFocusLine: expression(this.onFocus=this.blur());
}
```

But the best solution would still be the jQuery/javascript approach.

Comment: As i have mentioned in question I have already used outline and border property but still it is not working in html page but works in fiddle page

Comment: There is no way I can debug your HTML page, I can only see the code you post here. The CSS you authored looks messy, I suspect there is some validation issue. You can try to validate your code first and see if it helps.

Comment: Check my updated question. code is even w3c valid, there are no issue in code. I dnt think css looks messy coz there are only few lines. Can u pls copy the entire code in html page and run in ie then you can see that outline

Answer (score 1):

Support to the `outline` property was [added in IE 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc304063.aspx), so the technique does not work on IE 7. On newer versions, it does; your code, when tested on IE 9, works both in IE 9 mode and in IE 8 mode. (With “works” defined as “produces the desired usability problem”.)

To achieve the desired effect on IE 7, you can use the proprietary HTML attribute [`hidefocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533783%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), e.g.

```
<li><a href="#" style="color: black; " hidefocus>test 2</a></li>
```

or set the corresponding DOM property `hideFocus` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript on your page, try this, is working for me on IE9 and FF15:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        if (document.documentElement.attachEvent)
            document.documentElement.attachEvent('onmousedown', function(){event.srcElement.hideFocus=true});

    </script>
```